# Trigger a single function on multiple different events

Tags: javascript, function, events

I am making a function that appends objects to a text area with the following script:
[Project Page](https://theusaf.github.io/TI30XCalc) [Project Code](https://theusaf.github.io/TI30XCalc/calc.js)

```
inputNum.onchange = inputNum.onkeydown =  function(e){
        if(e.type == 'change' || (e.type = 'keydown' && e.keyCode == 13)){
            if(checkLength(inputNum.value,10) === true){
                inputNum.value = 9999999999;
            }

            //random variables and functions

            var j = 0;
            var m = setInterval(function(){
                if(j !== 0){
                    val = val * 40014;
                }
                if(val <= a){
                    if(useOpt === true){
                        res.value = res.value + "\n" + Math.round(Number((Number(val / div) * en) - sn));
                    }else{
                        res.value = res.value + "\n" + Number(Number(val / div) - Math.floor(val/div)).toFixed(5);
                    }
                }else{
                    var n = val;
                    n = l(n,a);
                    val = n;
                    console.log(n);
                    if(useOpt === true){
                        res.value = res.value + "\n" + Math.round(Number((Number(n / div) * en) - sn));
                    }else{
                        res.value = res.value + "\n" + Number(Number(n / div) - Math.floor(n/div)).toFixed(5);
                    }
                }
                j = j + 1;
                if(j == Number(rep.value)){
                    clearInterval(m);
                }
            },1);
            res.value = res.value.replace(/\n/,"");
        }
    };
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to run this function only once, when I press 'enter' on my input element. The resulting values from pressing 'enter' are:

```
0.00002
0.00002
0.74558
0.74558
```

instead of just 0.00002 and 0.74558 by themselves.
Is there a way that I can run the function only once when I press enter to change the input value? Also, I do not want to use jQuery for this. I would like the code to run both when the number is changed, but the key Enter isn't pressed and also when the key Enter is pressed and nothing is changed, and when the value is changed and the key Enter is pressed.

Comment: Check `e.keyCode === 13` (the ENTER key) and cancel the event in that case.

Comment: Try to remove `e.type == 'change' || ` form the top condition.

Comment: I would like that when you edit the value, and then click the window instead of pressing 'Enter' it would also run. Also, I would like the code to run even if you don't change the value, but press the enter key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good workaround I would suggest to *throttle* or *debounce* your handler body. There are many implementations and you may create your own one, but let's take the [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) with `trailing` option set to false:

```
var myHandler = function (e) { /* ... */ }
var myThrottledHandler = _.throttle(myHandler, 45, { trailing: false });
inputNum.onchange = inputNum.onkeydown = myThrottledHandler;
```

This would not allow to call your handler twice till 45ms is passed.

Comment: Hmm. So you are suggesting that I put some kind of timer to stop one event and make sure only one event runs?

Comment: @DanielLau Exactly. In case of two different triggers ('onChange' and 'onKeyEnter'), I guess, it will be appropriate solution.

Comment: @DanielLau Also, I think, if you have some **value** inside the handler's body, you may try following approach: 1) save that value in the outer scope, 2) add a first-line condition returning from the handler if that saved value matching a new one.